# Getting the DateTime for the end of a certain day

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the following

```
 DateTime today = DateTime.Today; // or DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
```

Now, I can not do something like this in Linq-EF because `Date` can not be translated to SQL:

```
 context.Records.Where(r => r.CreationDate.Date == today);
```

So, I always do something like this:

```
 DateTime dayEnd = today.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1);
 context.Records.Where(r => r.CreationDate >= today && r.CreationDate <= dayEnd);
```

Now, is there a better way for getting the end of time `DateTime` instead of adding one day then taking one millisecond?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with something like

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today ;
Context.Records.Where(r => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(r.CreationDate) == today) ;
```

is that underlying SQL is likely going to look something like this:

```
select *
from some_table r
where convert(date,r.CreationDate) == @today
```

Since the column is now a part of an *expression*, the SQL engine is unable to make use of any covering indices it has available. Unless you've got other criteria that will use indices, you're going to table scan. And with big tables, that will cause performance issue.

And you should avoid the obvious

```
DateTime today  = DateTime.Today ;
DateTime dayEnd = today.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1);
context.Records.Where(r => r.CreationDate >= today && r.CreationDate <= dayEnd) ;
```

because of the way SQL Server `datetime` values work: while they count in milliseconds, SQL Server's 'ticks' occur in 3- and 4-millisecond increments. For details, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7825370/467473) to the question [How does SqlDateTime do its precision reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824766/how-does-sqldatetime-do-its-precision-reduction). But in a nutshell:

> To do the conversion in the manner in which SQL Server does it, do the following:
>   Take the milliseconds portion of the actual time under consideration, a value from 0-999,
>   modulo 100. That gives you the low order digit, a value from 0-9. So if the current time
>   is 23:57:23.559, the milliseconds component is 559. Modulo 100 you get 9.
>
> 1. Values 0 and 1 are "rounded down" to 0.
> 2. Values 2, 3 and 4 are "rounded down"" to 3.
> 3. Values 5, 6, 7 and 8 are "rounded down" to 7.
> 4. A value of 9 is rounded **UP** to 0. This has a rather unpleasant and nasty side
>      effect: if the milliseconds portion of the time is 999, it ticks up 1 millisecond. This
>      means that the time 23:59:59.999 is rounded up to **THE NEXT DAY**. So conversion of '31
>      Dec 2010 23:59:59.999' yields a datetime value of...1 January 2011 00:00:00.000.

Note that `smalldatetime` also exhibits this kind of behavior. Only `datetime2` is exempt.

**So...**

Unless you're careful, it's really easy to drop things on the floor that have been timestamped right at end-of-day (don't ask how I know this).

You're better off doing something like

```
DateTime today    = DateTime.Today ;
DateTime tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);
context.Records.Where(r => r.CreationDate >= today && r.CreationDate < tomorrow) ;
```

which should translate into SQL that looks something like

```
select *
from some_table r
where r.CreationDate >= @today
  and r.CreationDate <  @tomorrow
```

and will allow the optimizer to make use of indices on the date/time column.

Comment: So, my method in used in the question is better?

Comment: @MIH: no. While SQL Server's `datetime` measure in milliseconds, it ticks its date/time clock in 3- and 4-millisecond increments. And the way it does so means that a `System.DateTime` value of `2013-12-31 23:59:59.999` is converted to the SQL Server `datetime` value  `2014-01-01 00:00:00.000`. See my amended answer for details.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
context.Records.Where(r => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(r.CreationDate) == today);
```

You can also skip `AddSeconds(-1)` by changing condition to `<`:

```
DateTime tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);
context.Records.Where(r => r.CreationDate >= today && r.CreationDate < tomorrow);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [EntityFunctions.TruncateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
context.Records.Where(r => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(r.CreationDate) == today);
```

Comment: Racing with Marcin ;)

Comment: @EvanL 15 seconds behind because of formatting link :)

Comment: @MIH better way to check day end is comparing with next day start

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy thanks! I guess I have to use the `<` operator instead of `<=`..

Answer (score 1):

Use SqlFunctions for "dayofyear" and "year":

```
context.Records.Where(r => 
SqlFunctions.DatePart("dayofyear", r.CreationDate) == DateTime.Now.DayOfYear 
&& SqlFunctions.DatePart("year", r.CreationDate) == DateTime.Now.Year);
```

Comment: It's about LINQ to Entities?

Comment: In that case, you would just use the SqlFunctions: `SqlFunctions.DatePart("dayofyear", r.CreationDate) == DateTime.Now.DayOfYear`

Comment: This will not work, for example, if I have this date ('01JAN2014') it will return all records created in first of JAN, regardless of the year..

Comment: Easy enough to add a fix for the year part of the query.